# substituting variables into object payloads

Tags: javascript

I am building an object to pass into a chartjs line chart and I'm looking to see if I can make it a little more dynamic.

Right now I have the following when building the data object, and it works a treat:

```
   var inboundEvent = {
     time: $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(message.data.payload.CreatedDate, 'HH:mm'),
     createdById: message.data.payload.CreatedById,
     key: message.data.payload.key__c,
     value: message.data.payload.value__c
    } 

    //add the most recent event to the array
    events.push(inboundEvent);
```

I want to create variables for key__c and value__c and then use the variable instead of the literal field name that is currently being used. The __c values are hardcoded field names coming off an event stream and i'd like to change it so that I could use the same code on a different event and pass the field names from that new event in dynamically.

This isn't (or doesn't seem like) a simple string concatenation..

Comment: This is an object literal, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var key__c   = "YOUR_KEY_HERE_0";
var value__c = "YOUR_KEY_HERE_1";
var inboundEvent = {
  time: $A.localizationService.formatDateTime(message.data.payload.CreatedDate, 'HH:mm'),
  createdById: message.data.payload.CreatedById,
  key: message.data.payload[key__c],
  value: message.data.payload[value__c]
}
```

Comment: boom! that's exactly it... thanks riyaz-ali!